# Dock icon under OSX in Java 9

Tags: java, macos, dock, java-9

I am trying to set the Dock icon in Java 9.

With previous versions of Java this was possible with something like 
`com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(image);`
but unfortunately with Java 9 the Application class is obsolete and inaccesible (maybe also missing?).

For all other tasks found in Application class, the `java.awt.Desktop` class took this functionality, all but the Dock manipulation.

In [JEP 272](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048731) this change is mentioned, as well as the idea that Dock is too much Apple-oriented (for me all are Apple oriented) and there is no clear explanation about it.

A Google search also has pre-9 information on how to deal with this.

Does anyone have any idea how's done now with Java 9?

Comment: You may be forced to find a JNA/JNI based solution

Comment: Of course with native programming, everything is possible. But it is funny that, although acknowledged, it is the only thing that is not implemented - all other methods are. Moreover handling images is not the most elegant method in native universe.

Comment: I've not seen Java 9 at all and it's always been a "joy" getting things to run on MacOS. There are a number of Windows centric APIs that do the "extra" stuff on window (progress bar in taskbar item for example), so it's not unreasonable to think that a MacOS based library could/should exist - if you think it needs to be updated, then you should make the suggestion as part of the improvement process

Comment: Yes, probably, but as I said the Desktop class in Java 9 is heavily polluted with all the mac stuff.. except the dock icon. I suspect that this functionality has moved to some onther class but it is practically impossible to find where.

Comment: Unless they've updated AWT/Swing (JavaFX?) `Window#setIconImages` to actually work under MacOS, I can't see away around it without using JNI/JNA

Comment: Unfortunately no... this was my first idea to try, with no luck

Comment: I'd consider that the bug that needs to be fixed :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [setIconImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Taskbar.html) in the new java.awt.Taskbar class?

Comment: The Taskbar.getTaskbar().setIconImage() worked for me in java 9

Comment: Works in Java 11